# Use different logger handlers for different levels

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I'd like to send all logs (including debug) to a file and to print only logs with a level of info or higher to stderr.

Currently, every module begins with this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

I haven't been able to achieve this without duplication of the logs (from the child and root loggers) and without modification of every module in my application.

What's the simplest way to do it?

Comment: Feel free to suggest edits to the question title; I'm not sure how widely applicable the solution will be and as such don't know what title to pick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure two different handlers:

```py
import logging
from logging import FileHandler, StreamHandler, INFO, DEBUG


file_handler = FileHandler("info.log")
file_handler.setLevel(DEBUG)

std_err_handler = StreamHandler()
std_err_handler.setLevel(INFO)

logging.basicConfig(handlers=[file_handler, std_err_handler], level=DEBUG)

logging.info("info")  # writes to file and stderr
logging.debug("debug")  # writes only to file
```

Comment: Thank you for the simple solution! My mistake was that I accidentally used `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` in a module that I imported before calling `basicConfig` in `__main__`.